# How to ignore deleted records using dbf-module in python?

Tags: python, foxpro, dbf

I'm using dbf-module by Ethan Furman version 0.96.005 (latest one) in Python 2.7 using old-fashioned FoxPro2.x-tables. Since I want to ignore deleted records, I set `tbl.use_deleted = False` after assigning `tbl = dbf.Table(dbf_path)`. I tried to set this before and after opening the table doing `with tbl.open('read-only') as tbl: ...`, but 
neither this nor that seems to have any effect.

On record-level I tried:

```
for rec in tbl:
    if not rec.has_been_deleted and ...
```

but that gave me:

```
FieldMissingError: 'has_been_deleted:  no such field in table'
```

Am I doing s.th. wrong? Or is that feature not available any more (as it was 5 years ago - see [Visual Fox Pro and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424106/visual-fox-pro-and-python))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use_deleted` and `has_been_deleted` no longer exist, and have been replaced with the function `is_deleted`.

So your choices at this point are (assuming a `from dbf import is_deleted`):

```
# check each record
for rec in tbl:
    if is_deleted(rec):
        continue
```

or

```
# create active/inactive indices

def active(rec):
    if is_deleted(rec):
        return DoNotIndex
    return dbf.recno(rec)

def inactive(rec):
    if is_deleted(rec):
        return recno(rec)
    return DoNotIndex

active_records = tbl.create_index(active)

deleted_records = tbl.create_index(inactive)
```

and then iterate through those:

```
# check active records
for rec in active_records:
    ...
```

Comment: Has the is_deleted been 'deleted' in version 0.97.11? I was having the same problem as the original post, came across the accepted solution. Have been trying it but get the NameError: name 'is_deleted' is not defined statement.

Comment: @snowman:  If you have only imported `dbf` (which is what I do) then you need to use `dbf.is_deleted()`.

Comment: I realized I had only import dbf. I changed to from dbf import * and it works.

Answer (score 0):

No existe definida is_deleted use esto:

## check each record

for rec in tbl:
if if rec._data[0] != "*":
continue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).